# How to share data between two components declared in lazy loaded different modules - Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-services

I want to implement a way to share data using common service between two components . Components are declared in two different module which loads in lazy manner.

**For Example:**

```
 { 
     path: 'user-profile', 
     loadChildren:'./user-profile/user-profile.module#UserProfileModule
 },
 { 
     path: 'login', 
     loadChildren:'./login/login.module#LoginModule',
 },
```

Here is my scenario. I'm fetching user profile related data upon login. I want to reuse those details in User Profile component. I don't want to make an API request to fetch the details as i return required detail on Login response.

I have a common data service in which i'm storing the detail.

```
@Injectable()
export class DataBusService {
public _userDetail:any = [];

  constructor() {
  }

  get userDetail() {
    return this._userDetail;
  }

  set userProfile(userDetail:UserDetail){
    _userDetail= userDetail;
  }
}
```

In this case, I set _userDetail from LoginComponent and get it in UserProfileComponent.

Below are the solutions I tried.

1. Added DataBusService as a provider in both the Login & UserProfile modules.
2. Created separate module for DataBusService and imported it in Login &
   UserProfile modules.
3. Declared DataBusService as "providedIn: 'root'".

None of the above solution worked because every time the new instance of DataBusService is created for the module.

I want to create a Singleton instance of DataBusService and use it in both Login and UserProfile components.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If your components have parent - child relation use `@input` and `@output`. If your components have sibling and grand-child relation than use `Services`.

Comment: @ShashikantDevani No there is not parent or child relation between the components. Both are independent components declared in different modules.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz for that? So i can help you

Comment: Also refer this link may this help you : https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/#Unrelated-Components-Sharing-Data-with-a-Service

Comment: @ShashikantDevani The solution given on the link you have provided will work fine if you have both components declared in same module. It will not work when you declare the components in different module and access the service data. The reason is, each module create their separate instance of service. So i want a way which create a single instance of service for the components declared in different modules.

Comment: Ok, don't provide your service into each module as a `provider`. Just provide into root module. Like App.module

Comment: I tried with option "providedIn: 'root'" available in Angular 6. Still did not work.

Comment: No i'm not asking about inside service this option is available inside service. `providedIn: 'root'`. I'm asking about `app.module` file.

Comment: **App.module** `@NgModule({  declarations: [ AppComponent  ],
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  providers: [EmployeeService], // Give reference of your service is here.
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
});`

Answer (score 1):

if you want your service to be singleton, please define and  provide it in your app's root module.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should use cookie or localstorage to store the data otherwise you will lose the data in page reload or service instance
eg. using localstorage
in LoginComponent

```
localstroage.setItem('item_id',item);
```

in UserProfileComponent

```
var data =localstorage.getitem('item_id');
```

Comment: Thanks. But I only seeking for a solution which provide a data sharing using service in mentioned scenario.